# How to create lightbox with popup window?

Tags: jquery

how to create lightbox with popup window

i am use multiple form with popup window how can i get a lightbox in popup window 
 and 
i want to close my popup window how can i do that thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[With one](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) [of the](http://www.jquerylightbox.com/) [many jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerylightbox_bal) [lightbox plugins](http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts)?

Comment: This proves that it was possible to understand and answer the question. Not everybody has years of experience writing in English.

Comment: Unfortunately SO can be a bit cut-throat when it comes to properly formed questions. Sometimes some leniency is required, as was the case here. It was clear that @hardik9045 wasn't a native English speaker and just needed a bit of help being pointed in the right direction. I think people who police SO can be a bit too quick to judge.